# How to load the actual .RData file, that is just called .RData (the compressed file that gets saved from a session)

Tags: r, rstudio

Similar questions, but not the question I have, were around loading a file that someone saved as **somefilename.RData**.  I am trying to do something different.

What I am trying to do is load the actual **.RData** file that gets saved from an R session.  The context is that I am using 2 different computers and am trying to download the .RData file from one computer and then load this same .RData file on a different computer in RStudio.

When I download the .RData file it shows up without the “.” (e.g., it shows up as RData).  When I try to rename it “.RData”, Windows will not allow me to do so.

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the ```load()``` function?

Comment: That is effectively what the Session > Load Workspace... did in Rstudio.   Thx

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this, I was able to load the file (even though it was called “RData“ and not called “.RData”, by using RStudio by going to Session > Load Workspace... and then navigating to that file.  I had used File > Open File... which did not work